# Using a string where clause with PredicateBuilder in LinqPad for creating dynamic where clause

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008-r2, linqpad

I am trying to create a dynamic query in LinqPad with PredicateBuilder enabled.

I first create a string that corresponds to the where clause for a query like '(orderid >100 AND customerid<=100)' and then try to use this string in building a LINQ query with PredicateBuilder. The dynamic query is represented by the variable 'dynamicResult' in code give at end of this post. The query is on Orders table of Northwind database in SQL Server 2008 R2.

The query throws this error in LinqPad, when I try to execute it:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

**Question:** How can I use a filter that is a string like '(orderid >100 AND customerid<=100)' with PredicateBuilder ? I had 'C# Statements' selected from LinqPad when trying to execute the below code.

I am trying to dynamically build a where condition for a LINQ query.

```
int? orderParam = 100;
string orderOperator = ">=";
string linqFilter = "";
linqFilter= String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", "o.OrderID", orderOperator, orderParam);
linqFilter.Dump();

 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Orders>();
 predicate = (linqFilter);
 var dynamicResult = from o in Orders.Where(predicate) select o;
 dynamicResult.Dump();
```

Comment: I think, PredicateBuilder needs an `IQueryable<T>`. so try this line - `var dynamicResult = from o in Orders.AsQueryable().Where(predicate) select o;`. Just check and let us know...

Comment: I think the problem is at this line line: predicate = (linqFilter), where the right side variable is a string being assigned to another type. Do you know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

Okay try something like this.

```
 var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Orders>();
 predicate = predicate.And(o => o.OrderID >= 100);
 var dynamicResult = from o in Orders.Where(predicate) select o;
```

As you have said you used **linqfilter** string. it means you needs to build expression dynamically. So for that here is one [good article in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493917/Dynamic-Querying-with-LINQ-to-Entities-and-Express). For you refer **"Dynamic Where"** section in that article. You definitely get the hint from that section.

Comment: I wanted to use a string like linqFilter in my code snippet with PredicateBuilder. In your example you have not used a string but an expression.

Comment: @Sunil: I have updated my answer...Just go thru that article.